# cmake find_library not working even with absolute path

Tags: cmake

I have a make file which will not find a library.

In my make file, i have put the following (messages for debug):

```
find_library(TINYXML_LIB NAMES "libtinyxml2.a" HINTS "/var/lib/yocto/tmpdir/tmp_20210713/work/znver1-poky-linux/radeon-dev-tool/1.0-r0/Common/Lib/Ext/tinyxml2/Lib/Linux/x64/Release/")
 message("#############")
 message(${TINYXML_LIB})
 message("#############")
```

The output of this is like this:

```
 #############
 TINYXML_LIB-NOTFOUND
 #############
```

If i do a ls on the path, i see the file:

```
> ls /var/lib/yocto/gallium/tmpdir/tmp_20210713/work/znver1-poky-linux/radeon-dev-tool/1.0-r0/Common/Lib/Ext/tinyxml2/Lib/Linux/x64/Release/
libtinyxml2.a
```

I also tried to use `find_file()` but that gave the same result.

why does this fail when the file is obviously there?

edit: Even this will produce the same result:

```
set(TINYXML_LIB, test)
message("#############")
message(${TINYXML_LIB})
message("#############")
```

Still gives me the same output:

```
 #############
 TINYXML_LIB-NOTFOUND
 #############
```

As pointed out by Tsyvarev  there was a missing part of my path.
However, editing the line to `find_library(TINYXML_LIB NAMES "libtinyxml2.a" HINTS "/var/lib/yocto/gallium/tmpdir/tmp_20210713/work/znver1-poky-linux/radeon-dev-tool/1.0-r0/Common/Lib/Ext/tinyxml2/Lib/Linux/x64/Release/")` still produces the same result.

For the set command, it works now as i removed the comma :)

Comment: You missed the forth component of the path: `gallium`. (By search on the question page you can easily find that paths are different). As for the `set` command, its arguments are separated by **spaces**, not by *comma*. That is, your assignment sets the variable `TINYXML_LIB,`. (Yes, with terminating comma.)

Comment: Good catch, sadly i still have the problem with the find lib not finding the file, but i can now correctly set the variable (without a comma ;) )

Comment: I would recommend removing your build directory and then restarting the build. It could be that something is cached in there.

Answer (score 2):

Likely you have a cache problem, and deleting the cache (or the entire build directory) and starting from scratch would solve your problem.

However, if you have the full path to your library, then there is no need to `find_library`. Just link to it directly:

```
target_link_library(target PUBLIC full_path_to_lib)
```